# Error Playing File: NullPointerException in Android

Tags: java, android, error-handling, android-mediaplayer

I want to play an mp3 file in android, but i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at HelloAndroid.playMusic
```

My code below

```
package com.bestvalue.hello;
/*import android.util.Log;*/
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {

    public static final String DebugTag = "LogInfo";
    public MediaPlayer mp;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);        
        tv.setText("keke napep");
        playMusic();
        setContentView(tv);        
        Log.i(DebugTag, "Info about my app na");                
    }


    public void playMusic () {
        try {
            Uri fileName = Uri.parse("http://www.perlgurl.org/podcast/archives/podcasts/PerlgurlPromo.mp3");
            mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, fileName);
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(DebugTag, "Error Playing File", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

What will i do to fix this error?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
package com.bestvalue.hello;
/*import android.util.Log;*/
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;


public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {

    public static final String DebugTag = "LogInfo";
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);        
        tv.setText("keke napep");
        playMusic();
        setContentView(tv);                           
    }

    public void playMusic () {
        try {
            String url = "http://www.perlgurl.org/podcast/archives/podcasts/PerlgurlPromo.mp3";
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.prepare(); 
            mp.start();         
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(DebugTag, "Error Playing File", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

After implementing some of the answers, i now get this error: `java.io.IOException: Prepare Failed .: status = 0x1`

Answer (score 1):

add `mp.prepare();` before mp.start();

Comment: i just added it, did not seem to help

Comment: refer this link  http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you aren't checking `mp` before you call methods on it. According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29), if `MediaPlayer.create` fails, it will return `null`.

Rule of thumb with `NullPointerException`s: go back and check your returns. Something is usually returning `null` when you aren't expecting it to, and you try to call a method on it. In this case, you aren't calling anything on `fileName`, so that's safe. You're calling something on `mp`, so that's probably what's doing you in.

[edit]

Why the audio isn't playing:

You aren't calling `setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` and the use of URIs in the creation of a `MediaPlayer` instance is only for locally stored media. Network media needs to have its location set by calling `setDataSource(context, uri);`.

From [the (very good) documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html):

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();`
```

Comment: As @Ilango J notes below, you need a call to mp.prepare();. I'd take a moment and look at the flow chart created in the docs, were I you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: maybe there is something i am not getting right, but nothing changed

Comment: Updated to point to the documentation and point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: thanks, the error message is now different: java.io.IOException: Prepare Failed .: statue = 0x1

Comment: Please update your code. My bet is you're still calling a URI-- setDataSource wants a String.

Comment: @PaddyForan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2053/discussion-between-ogugua-belonwu-and-paddy-foran)